# Is there no UMVUE for this case?

Tags: estimation, umvue

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ be $\operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$

I seem to recall it said that there is no UMVUE for $\mu$ if $\sigma^2$ is also unknown but cannot find why this is so. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

The complete sufficient statistics for this model are $\bar{X}$ and $s^2$ (the sample mean and variance). Since we have $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}]=\mu$, by Rao-Blackwell and its corollaries $\bar{X}$ is the UMVUE for $\mu$.

Comment: The independence of sample mean and sample variance under normal is also needed for this, correct?

Comment: Nope. Since the sufficient statistics are complete, any function of them that is an unbiased estimate of a function of a parameter is the UMVUE of that function of a parameter.